# Easier way to work with single element arrays in Mustache

Tags: arrays, json, mustache

I'm dealing with an external API that return lots of single element arrays.  For example:

```
items: [ 
    itemDetails: [ 
        titles: [
            'My First Title'
               ]
    ],
    itemDetails: [ 
        titles: [
            'My Second Title'
               ]
    ]
]
```

If I use mustache.js and I want to display the title I don't think I can do this because I need to loop through itemDetails and titles:

```
{{#items}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{itemDetails[0].titles[0]}}</td>
      </tr>
{{/items}}
```

Is there an easy way to do this assuming I always want the 0 element of every array?

Answer (score 0):

I did just stumble across [this](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/158).  I wasn't expecting you can do this, but it looks like this will work without having to loop through each subitem:

```
{{#items}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{itemDetails.0.titles.0}}</td>
      </tr>
{{/items}}
```